# не работает на github pages ajax запрос post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
          $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "../server.php",
                data: json,
                dataType: "script",
                error: function() {
                    alert("В запросе была ошибка")
                },
                success: function() {
                    modal.css({"display": "none"});
                    thanks.css({"display": "block", "top": "0px"});

                    backBtn.on("click", function() {
                        thanks.animate({
                            top: "-550px"
                        }, 1000, function() {
                            modal.css({"display": "none"});
                        })
                        overlay.animate({
                            "opacity": "hide"
                        }, 1000)
                    })
                }
            })
```

Через локальный сервер работает а через гитхаб нет. В чем может быть проблема https://kamran92.github.io/dz3/#tour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub Pages разрешает размещать только статический контент (html, css, js, картинки и т.д.), PHP скрипты он не хостит для этого нужен полноценный хостинг ([Docs](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages)):

> GitHub Pages is a static site hosting service that takes HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files straight from a repository on GitHub

В вашем же случае вы пытаетесь сделать запрос на https://kamran92.github.io/server.php, который GitHub и отклоняет как 405 Method Not Allowed, так как POST запрос бессмысленно разрешать для статических файлов.